# Send data from Activities with setResult is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I need some help with my design... it seems to be wrong.
I have a `BaseActivity` which contains a `ViewPager` with a `TabLayout`. Every item in `ViewPager` is a `Fragment`.

So, one of my fragments opens a new Activity, which uses `zxing minimal library` to scan QRCodes.

I need to send QRCode data back to my BaseActivity, when QRCode is captured. I heard about using `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` but it's not working.

Also, when it works, I need to update my fragment with captured data.
Here's some code (I can provide further if necessary):

**QRCodeListFragment**

```
//qrCodeList is an ArrayList<String>
if (cameraButton != null) {
    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), CameraActivity.class);
            cameraActivity.putExtra("QRCODE_LIST", qrCodeList);
            cameraActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivityForResult(cameraActivity, 1);
            }
        });
    }
```

**CameraActivity**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator
        .parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (scanResult != null) {
        qrCodeList.add(scanResult.getContents());
        onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("QRCODE_LIST", qrCodeList);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

**BaseActivity**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case (1) : {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(QRCODE_POSITION, true);
                // HOW TO UPDATE QRCODELISTFRAGMENT WITH DATA?
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change code 
    startActivityForResult(cameraActivity, 1);
To 
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(cameraActivity, 1);